# OpenCV - C++ - How to merge blobs/bounding boxes in close proximity?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

Thanks in advance...

I am working to detect vehicles in a moving video, and in that process I count the number of cars that have passed.

[image]

In this picture, you can see that it can detect the sedan nicely, but the large image (the bus) is not being represented as one large blob like I want it to be. Instead, it thinks that the bus is actually a bunch of cars next to each other.

Psuedo code would look something like this:

```
if (blob[i].center is close to blob[i + 1].center)
    mergeBlobs;
```

Steps before below code: Convert to gray, frame difference, threshold, dilate(x2), erode, find counters...

Here is the bulk of the code I have written:

```
vector<vector<Point> > contours;                            //Not sure what this does but it works
findContours(dil, contours, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);    
vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly(contours.size());              
vector<Rect> boundRect(contours.size());                            
vector<vector<Point> > hull(contours.size());

Mat output = Mat::zeros(dil.rows, dil.cols, CV_8UC3);
int counter = 0;                                                    
line(output, Point(0, output.rows / 2), Point(output.cols, output.rows / 2), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 3, 8);  //As cars pass this line, CarCount++

for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true);      
    boundRect[i] = boundingRect(Mat(contours_poly[i]));             
    convexHull(Mat(contours[i]), hull[i], false);                   

    if ((boundRect[i].width * boundRect[i].height) > 10000)         //If the bounding rectangle has an area less than 10,000 then just ignore it completely
    {
        counter = counter + 1;
        drawContours(output, hull, i, Scalar(255, 255, 255), CV_FILLED);    //draw contours of convexHull. 

        rectangle(output, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2, 8, 0); //Draws the actual rectangle around the contours
        putText(output, to_string(counter), Point(boundRect[i].x, boundRect[i].y), FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 3, Scalar(255, 0, 0), 3, 8);
        if ((boundRect[i].y > ((output.rows / 2) - 6)) && (boundRect[i].y < ((output.rows / 2) + 6)))
        {
            CarCount++;                                                 //Global car count
            Mat croppedImage = frameGray(Rect(boundRect[i].x, boundRect[i].y, boundRect[i].width, boundRect[i].height));
            imshow("Cropped Image", croppedImage);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should use MOG to extract difference regions(the potential cars regions)